# Link to next page using ERB/jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, url, counter, erb

In my rails app I have the follow URL path 'http://localhost/Teamleader/1', this gives me the first team leader and renders the view.

I'm trying to add a next link in my show.html.erb, so far I have the follow code:

```
<div id="home_link"> <%= link_to "Home" %> </div>
```

For testing sake, here is my jquery code:

```
$('#next_link').bind('click', function () {

      var url = "/teamleader/" + SOME_COUNTER_HERE
      if (url) { 
          window.location.replace(url);
      }
      return false;
  });
```

After the user clicks, I want the page to go to 'Teamleader/2', and from 'Teamleader/2' to '/3' and so forth.
Am I approaching this problem the right way? Or should this be done through the rails helper, path_to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely should use path helper

```
<%= link_to "next_link", teamleader_path(Teamleader.where("id > ?", @teamleader.id).order("id ASC").first) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

in controller:

```
@next_link_counter = LeaderBoard.where("id > ?", params[:id]).first
```

In view:

```
<div id="next_link">
  <%= link_to "next_link", "/leaderboard/#{@next_link_counter}" %> 
</div>
```

Comment: Evgeniy beat you to it, but your answer is very much appreciated. Helpful for a beginner like me!